# How to replace Fragment from Activity Above FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, listactivity, searchview

I need assistance problem solving.  Not necessarily looking for code, though that wouldn't be rejected!

I have a central `FragmentActivity` housing a `FrameLayout` that I use to swap `Fragments` as the user navigates around the core of the app.

On my `ActionBar` is a search widget.  Typing in a search query opens up a `ListActivity` of List Options that matched the query.  So this is essentially opening up an `Activity` *over* my `FragmentActivity`.  I like that idea as this is "side detour" in navigation.

**My problem I need to solve is this:**  When the user selects List Item after search, I want to somehow close `Activity`, and replace the FrameLayout in the Fragment Activity "underneath" with the information that they searched for.

I tried to make the `ListActivity` a `ListFragment` but couldn't work that out.  Unless making it a `FragmentActivity` with an enclosing `Fragment` is the answer. - Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try starting the `ListActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` method, and in your `FragmentActivity` override the `onActivityResult()` method, and make all the magic there.

Comment: I didn't even think of this, wow, great point! I've already got this implemented elsewhere in my app

Comment: Hope that this will solve your problem. For simple tasks this is the easiest way, and you don't have to declare new interfaces for object communication.

Answer (score 1):

Could you implement a callback method in the Activity so that the FragmentActivity could respond to whatever the Activity wished to convey?